# RIGHT() / LEFT() functions

Tags: string, hive, hiveql

Is there a function in Hiveql that is equivalent to `Right()` or `Left()` function from TSQL? For example, `RIGHT(col1,10)` to get the first 10 characters from `col1`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no `right` or `left` function, but you can implement the same functionality with `substr`, like this:

```
left(column, nchar) = substr(column, 1* nchar)

right(column, nchar) = substr(column, (-1)* nchar)
```

Here `nchar` is number of characters.

Comment: Can `(-1)*` be changed to `-1,`? It is a typo?

Comment: I found I had to use `SUBSTR(column, start, num_chars)`as per docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

eg. `substr(column, 0, 3)` gives the first 3 chars in the a string.

Answer (score 9):

This works: `substr (col, -nchar) = right(col, nchar)`.

```
hive> select substr('adbcefghij',-4);
ghij
Time taken: 40.839 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: For the win! I've proposed an update to the WRONG 'accepted' answer to use this formula, which is also simpler than ALEKSEY NIKITOV's (which is also correct.) Thanks anonyXmous!

Answer (score 6):

```
right(column, nchar) = substr(column, (length(column)-nchar+1), nchar)
```

Comment: This is almost the same as the answer given 10 months ago.

Comment: Almost the same, except this one is correct and the other was incorrect.

Comment: @BrianMorearty Then the accepted answer should be edited