How to match only matched numbers between two columns
I have two columns named id and custid and want to match the data by excluding additional data( starting from last position and backwards) in custid column.
Sample data :
Id  custid
12345 AP0012345
67890 TS0067890

I want result like below after writing SQL query:
Id   custid
12345 12345
67890 67890

Note : the format is fixed in both the columns.
Looking for some suggestions.
Thanks
Suggestions on my question.

please show us what yout tried so far.

select id,id as custid from sampledata?

you can use substring for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435889/right-left-functions and cast like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346750/hive-convert-string-to-integer

Add some more sample table data, including non-matches.

Column data types?

Hive will take a negative argument to substring from the right - substring(custid, -5) will get the last 5 characters.

Use the Substring function
select Id, substring(custid,5,5) as 'custid' ..........
